# A unary operator function expression is ~5261% faster than a brackets function expression in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox

In this [test](http://jsperf.com/function-expressions), I am looking at two different ways of function expressions; using the exclamation point unary operator and using brackets.

The following are the 2 tests:

```
var f = !function() {};

var f = (function() {});
```

Given the results below, I was intrigued when I saw that the unary operator test was ~5261% faster than the brackets test in Firefox.

[image]

[image]

What sort of optimization is going on that amounts to such a significant increase in performance in Firefox, dwarfing the other browsers?

Comment: Seeems like a pointless comparision between two things that generate different results.  What would you use the first construction for in the real world?  It does not do the same thing as the second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is resulting in a `boolean`, and the second one a `function`. There doesn't seem to be much real-world significance to your test.

> *"What sort of optimization is going on that amounts to such a significant increase in performance in Firefox, dwarfing the other browsers?"*

I suppose Firefox has an optimization that avoids creation of the function object since it is never actually used, but that's just a guess.

---

[Here's an updated jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/function-expressions/3). This one adds two tests that create boolean values. Notice that they're very close to the "Exclamation" test in Firefox.

This lends support to the idea that Firefox has this particular optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in a more "real-life" example, the difference is no longer really imporant.

Those expressions are most likely used to create an outer function context to encapsulate your code from the global context, like

```
!function() {
}();

(function() {
}());
```

See results for that here: http://jsperf.com/function-expressions/2

You actually double the work for the engine there. But assigning a function to a variable you implicitly create a *function expression*

```
var f = function() {};
```

Also applying the `!` operator, is unnecessary work.

Comment: Yes when I tried tests which actually invoke the functions, I got results in which the delta was insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting somewhere around 1e9 operations per second on the "exclamation" case.  Your CPU probably does somewhere around 1-4 billion clock ticks per second.  so that case is taking around 1-4 clock ticks.

What that means is that the entire thing got optimized away to "f = false" by the JIT.  Most likely because type inference detected that unary "!" is always followed by an object, and optimized it to "false".

One reason it's slower in Chrome is that in Chrome there are objects for which unary "!" returns true, so the optimization I describe above is invalid there.